# React typescript Parsing error: '{' expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm using react + typescript and get this error. Parsing error: '{' expected
how to fix it?.

here is my code snippet

```
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.collection);
    return (
      <div className='body-container'>
        <Container>
          {this.collection.items.map(collection => {
              <Card>
                <Card.Image>
                  <Image.Container size='3by4'>
                    <Image src=collection.coverLink />
                  </Image.Container>
                </Card.Image>
              </Card>
            });
          }
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Remove the semi colon after the closing parenthesis for `this.collection.items.map(...`

Answer (score 4):

> Parsing error: '{' expected

You need to wrap the attribute in `{`

```
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.collection);
    return (
      <div className='body-container'>
        <Container>
          {this.collection.items.map(collection => {
            <Card>
              <Card.Image>
                <Image.Container size='3by4'>
                  <Image src={collection.coverLink} /> {/*fix here*/}
                </Image.Container>
              </Card.Image>
            </Card>
          })} {/*another fix here*/}
      </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Also removed the semicolon ;).

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `;`

```
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.collection);
    return (
      <div className='body-container'>
        <Container>
          {this.collection.items.map(collection => {
              <Card>
                <Card.Image>
                  <Image.Container size='3by4'>
                    <Image src=collection.coverLink />
                  </Image.Container>
                </Card.Image>
              </Card>
            }); // Remove ;
          }
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change {} by ()

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.collection);
    return (
      <div className='body-container'>
        <Container>
          {this.collection.items.map(collection => (
              <Card>
                <Card.Image>
                  <Image.Container size='3by4'>
                    <Image src=collection.coverLink />
                  </Image.Container>
                </Card.Image>
              </Card>
            ))
          }
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Or make Card inside return()

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state.collection);
    return (
      <div className='body-container'>
        <Container>
          {this.collection.items.map(collection => {
              return(
              <Card>
                <Card.Image>
                  <Image.Container size='3by4'>
                    <Image src=collection.coverLink />
                  </Image.Container>
                </Card.Image>
              </Card>
              )
            })
          }
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to add `{}` around the prop to Image component, like this:
 `<Image src={collection.coverLink} />`.

Sencondy, you are not returning anything from the function in map.

WRONG:

```
{this.collection.items.map(collection => {
    <Card>
      <Card.Image>
        <Image.Container size='3by4'>
          <Image src={collection.coverLink} />
        </Image.Container>
      </Card.Image>
    </Card>
  });
}
```

GOOD:

```
{this.collection.items.map(collection => (
    <Card>
      <Card.Image>
        <Image.Container size='3by4'>
          <Image src={collection.coverLink} />
        </Image.Container>
      </Card.Image>
    </Card>
  ));
}
```

OR:

```
{this.collection.items.map(collection => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Card.Image>
          <Image.Container size='3by4'>
            <Image src={collection.coverLink} />
          </Image.Container>
        </Card.Image>
      </Card>
    );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed flower brackets  , add the following

Use it to  wrap the value of "src" attribute

```
 <Image src={collection.coverLink} />
```